# What's the difference between setq and defvar

Tags: defvar, setq

What is the difference between `setq` and `defvar` in Emacs lisp?

I see common lisp version of the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855862.  Are they same in Elisp?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should **ask Emacs** this question: **`C-h i`**, choose the Elisp manual (**`m Elisp`**), and search the index for "defvar" (**`i defvar`**).  That takes you to node [Defining Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html).

Emacs tells you that `defvar` allows attaching a *doc string*, and that if the variable *already has a value then it does nothing*.

It also tells you about the use of `defvar` with no value to be assigned: `(defvar foo)`.  It tells you that that *declares the variable to be dynamically scoped*.

`setq` has none of those properties.

`defvar` and `setq` are similar, but not quite the same, in Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp.

[*Read more, to learn more.*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html)

Comment: In fact defvar also declares "dynamical scoping" if there is a value given, and that remains true even if the variable already had a value. OTOH "if the variable already has a value then it does nothing" is true for all valid uses of defvar (and the bytecompiler should issue a warning in the remaining cases, i.e. if declaring a variable after its first use).

Comment: so it sounds like `defvar` is a global variable (as in imperative programming style) and a convention for customization, while setq is more like a let binding in functional programming languages (with dynamic/lexical scoping rule depending of which global scoping mode is active.........)

Comment: @nicolas: Please read the manual. `setq` sets a var value, regardless of whether the var (occurrence) is local. `defvar` declares a var as global. (It may also be "buffer-local": `local-variable-p`.) A var occurrence bound as a function arg or by `let` is "local" in the usual sense. If a var bound by `let` etc. is global (or buffer-local) then a local binding (usual sense) is created for it, for the duration/scope of that `let`. Within that binding scope, `setq` changes the local value. It's better to talk about a var *occurrence* being local (on stack) or global (on heap) than a var being so.

Comment: @drew I did. I confess I dont quite understand everything, apart from `defvar` being a global variable. It looks absolutely mad to have a 2 page explanation for binding, but your help is precious for navigating the manual, so thank you

Comment: @nicolas: Take your time reading it and rereading it. Sometimes what it says is precise but hard to grasp, like a formal specification. Once you get it, it could be helpful for you to `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest improvements that might help others get it easier.

Comment: @nicolas: Start with understanding a variable on *the heap* (aka a global or buffer-local variable). You likely already understand true local variables, that is, variables on *the stack*. Googling might also help.

Comment: @Drew thanks for your tips and for the context you provide in your answer

Comment: @nicolas If you're at all familiar with other languages, one of the distinctions here is between variable *definition* (`int foo;`) and variable *assignment* (`foo = 42`). `setq` is assignment, and it doesn't care about the scope/lifetime of what it's assigning to (`foo = 42;` doesn't care if `foo` is global, local, or whatever). `defvar` is definition, which of course can optionally contain assignment of an initial value (`int foo = 42;`).