# init.el - setq or defvar

Tags: init-file, variables

I want to define a trash directory in my `user-init-file` but I don't know which way to do this is best or most correct. I currently have something like this:

```el
(defvar my-trash-dir
  (expand-file-name ".trash" user-emacs-directory))
(if (not (file-exists-p my-trash-dir))
    (make-directory my-trash-dir))
(setq trash-directory my-trash-dir)
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this, maybe by using `setq` or `defconst`?

Comment: See also [`(eintr) defvar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defvar.html) and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29710/15748. I'm not flagging this question as a duplicate of the latter because it is more focussed on which form is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the sole purpose of defining `my-trash-dir` is to use its value to set the user option `trash-directory`, then you should just write

```el
(setq trash-directory (expand-file-name ".trash" user-emacs-directory))
```

or (if you don't mind wasting a millisecond or two at startup) even

```el
(setq trash-directory (locate-user-emacs-file ".trash"))
```

This is because `trash-directory` is automatically created for you when the command `move-file-to-trash` is invoked. Deferring the creation of `trash-directory` until it is actually needed will even improve your startup time.

---

If, however, you want to use `my-trash-dir` as a variable for other purposes, there is nothing wrong with using a plain `setq` to define it:

```el
(setq my-trash-dir (locate-user-emacs-file ".trash"))
(setq trash-directory my-trash-dir)
(unless (file-exists-p my-trash-dir)
  (make-directory my-trash-dir))
```

There is almost never a need for users to use `defconst`, especially given the Emacs philosophy centred around customisability. But there are several advantages to using a `defvar`:

```el
(defvar my-trash-dir (locate-user-emacs-file ".trash")
  "Personal Emacs trash directory.")

(setq trash-directory my-trash-dir)
(unless (file-exists-p my-trash-dir)
  (make-directory my-trash-dir))
```

1. You can associate a docstring with it which will be presented by <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`my-trash-dir`<kbd>RET</kbd> and reduces the need for comments in your code.
2. Emacs notes the file in which the variable was defined. You can then jump to this location via <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-variable`<kbd>RET</kbd> or the hyperlinked button in the `*Help*` buffer.
3. The byte-compiler is made aware of the variable so that it does not complain, should you want to byte-compile your code. The variable also satisfies `special-variable-p`, should you ever care about this.
4. You will be one step closer to achieving Emacs zen<sup>[1]</sup>. In other words, it is more idiomatic and elegant to define variables prior to their use.

   <sub>[1]: This claim is provided "as-is", without warranty of any kind.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I think Basil gave you the best answer, but just for completeness, you can also use `let` in your example:

```
(let ((my-trash-dir
       (expand-file-name ".trash" user-emacs-directory))
  (if (not (file-exists-p my-trash-dir))
      (make-directory my-trash-dir))
  (setq trash-directory my-trash-dir))
```

Answer (score 2):

That will work just fine, but you can simplify it:

```
(setq trash-dir (expand-file-name ".trash" user-emacs-directory))
(if (not (file-exists-p trash-dir))
    (make-directory trash-dir))
```